# Dataframe updating in results but not when View() is used?

Tags: r

I have a markdown doc that shows the results of me changing a variable from 1 column (Industries) with multiple values in each cell, into a wide format where each value is now its own variable with values for TRUE or FALSE if it exists in a row from the initial single industries column.

When I run this code the results below the code show the wide format with TRUE/FALSE etc appropriately, but when i use View() to look at the wide format dataframe on its own, it just shows the single original Industries column with multiple values in each cell and I cant work out why.

Any ideas? I need to be able to merge my new wide set into a new dataset but as its still in the single column format i cant until I can work out why its not showing up properly.

[Code and results showing successful wide variable layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNPpp.png)

[Dataframe not showing wide variable layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZNVp.png)

Comment: Fixed it. I never assigned the changes to something new. I just needed to add a df <- at the start of the second chunk and then view that df instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I never assigned the changes to something new. I just needed to add a df <- at the start of the second chunk and then view that df instead.